# put an image div on top of image(s) with retina effect

Tags: javascript, ipad, ios5, retina-display

I have a page with the [retina effect](http://zoom-test.magent-server.de/zoom1.html), and I'm trying to put an image in a separate div on top. How would I go about that?

It is different, because you can't simply add it in, and z-index messes it up as well.the body is set up as follows

```
    <body>
    <div id="bar"></div> //this shows under the anchor, and wont go above
<div id="text"><img src="images/text.jpg" style="height:232px; width:1024; position:absolute; top:536px; left:0;"/></div>
    <a href="images/IDPlarge.jpg" class="cloud-zoom" rel="position: 'inside', showTitle: false">
        <img src="images/IDPfit.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
   //putting it here makes no difference
</body>
```